# MetricsSnapshotReporterFactory warning in samza job

Tags: apache-samza

I get the following warning in samza job:

> [main] WARN o.a.s.m.r.MetricsSnapshotReporterFactory.warn(66) - Unable
>   to find implementation version in jar's meta info. Defaulting to
>   0.0.1.

How can i fix it? What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a benign warning. It means that your StreamTask implementation (the class pointed by "task.class") does not list a version in the jar. 
You can ignore it. 
If you would like to include versioning information within the jar, you can add a Manifest.txt to your jar as per guidelines [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html). This should get rid of the warning. 
I can think of a scenario where you want to distinguish metrics published from one version of your Samza job to another. In such cases, adding versioning information to your Manifest file helps. HTH!